# Recursive programming in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Can we use recursion in Odoo's function?
In my code below

```
def create_lines(self, item_id=None, parent_id=None):
    source_items = self.env['product.source']
    duplicate_items = self.env['product.duplicate']
    recs = source_items.search([['parent_id', '=', item_id]])
    for rec in recs:
        value = {   'parent_id': parent_id,
                    'name': rec.name,
                    'date': rec.date,
                    'description': rec.description
                }
        line = duplicate_items.create(value)
        self.create_lines(self, rec.id, line.id)
```

I'm getting `SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread`

Why is this happening? And how can we enable recursion in Odoo?

Comment: Try removing self parameter when calling again the function, not totally related to the message tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the error happened because I'm using `interactive python debugger`  `ipdb.set_trace();` inside the recursion.

Also I need to correct my recursion like this

```
def create_lines(self, item_id=False, parent_id=False):
    source_items = self.env['product.source']
    duplicate_items = self.env['product.duplicate']
    recs = source_items.search([['parent_id', '=', item_id]])
    for rec in recs:
        value = {   'parent_id': parent_id,
                    'name': rec.name,
                    'date': rec.date,
                    'description': rec.description
                }
        line = duplicate_items.create(value)
        childs = source_items.search([['parent_id', '=', rec_id]])
        if (len(childs)):
            self.create_lines(self, rec.id, line.id)
```

So it doesn't recursive infinitely.

Comment: You can find at `https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/` thant for sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false `if not seq: or if seq:` not `if len(seq):
     or if not len(seq):`